# Output of two if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, output

Why does the following output "Resting" and "Studying?" Shouldn't it just be "Studying"?

```
    boolean isSleeping = false;
    boolean isStudying = true;
    if (isSleeping)
        System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
        System.out.println(" Resting ");
    if (isStudying)
        System.out.println(" Studying ");
```

Comment: Because `System.out.println(" Resting ");` is not inside the first if statement.

Comment: braces define scope of blocks..

Comment: This is a very good reason to [never use braceless-ifs](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/)

Comment: @Jongware then he would not use ";" at line ends and he would write `if isSleeping":"` :D:D:D

Answer (score 3):

Basically, because you've not enclosed the first if statements content in between `{...}`, it's basically the qualivent as saying...

```
if (isSleeping)
    System.out.println(" Sleeping ");

System.out.println(" Resting ");

if (isStudying)
    System.out.println(" Studying ");
```

Instead, trying using...

```
if (isSleeping) {
    System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
    System.out.println(" Resting ");
}
if (isStudying) {
    System.out.println(" Studying "); 
}
```

This is one of the reasons why it's encouraged to use braces around your conditional statements

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isSleeping)
    System.out.println(" Sleeping "); // your if condition's scope ends here
    System.out.println(" Resting ");// always printed
if (isStudying)
    System.out.println(" Studying "); // your second if condition's scope ends here
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{ }` if you want to execute two statements.

Like this:

```
if (isSleeping) {
    System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
    System.out.println(" Resting ");
}
else if (isStudying) {
    System.out.println(" Studying ");
}
```

I have edited and added the `else` also, because *symentically* someone sleeping or resting isn't studying.

Answer (score 1):

Add curly braces after if statement if you want more statements to be executed for that condition.

```
boolean isSleeping = false;
    boolean isStudying = true;
    if (isSleeping){
        System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
        System.out.println(" Resting ");
    }
    if (isStudying)
        System.out.println(" Studying ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not use `{...}` for your if statements. So, it considers the second line out of your `if`.

Try this:

```
boolean isSleeping = false;
boolean isStudying = true;
if (isSleeping) {                         // the following code between brackets will be executed.
    System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
    System.out.println(" Resting ");
}
if (isStudying)
    System.out.println(" Studying ");     // Without bracket, it executes only the line until the semi-colon.
```

Answer (score 1):

Read what is scope: [SCOPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/scope.html)

The `if` statement without `{` and `}` has as scope the first line of code after condition..

However if you want print only sleeping you must do:

```
    boolean isSleeping = false;
    boolean isStudying = true;

    if (isSleeping){
        System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
    }

        System.out.println(" Resting ");

    if (isStudying){
        System.out.println(" Studying ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(true)
line 1
line 2
```

above if statement is without brackets {}..which means the if statement is applicable to only the line (line 1) just after the if Statement..

but

```
if(true)
{
line 1
line 2
}
```

the if statement above with brackets is al=pplicable on the whole body of brackets..this is applicable for both line 1 and line 2..

SO in your case

```
if (isSleeping)
    System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
    System.out.println(" Resting ");
```

this IF statement is only applicable for first line "Sleepinfg"..so "Resting" is free of any IF statement..so "Resting" will always be in the output file

your code should be like this..

```
boolean isSleeping = false;
boolean isStudying = true;
if (isSleeping)
{
    System.out.println(" Sleeping ");
    System.out.println(" Resting ");
} 
if (isStudying)
{
   System.out.println(" Studying ");
}
```